# Combining multiple records to output a single result

Tags: sql, pivot

I am searching a parts table and would like to separate the data results into columns by company number. Each record uses the company number and part number and a few other key fields to make them unique. I would like to find the part number and populate a single row with all the company numbers as columns. If the part is found in a company the matching column and row are populated with 1 or true otherwise 0 or null.

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT PartNumber,CompanyNumber FROM DB.PartsTable PartsTable
WHERE PartNumber = &findPartNumber AND status= '1'
```

This shows what I have and the results I would like to get:

[image: expected output]

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+pivot)

Answer (score 0):

```
Below would be the query -

select
sum(case when col#=601 then 1 else 0 end) as 601 ,
sum(case when col#=603 then 1 else 0 end) as 603,
sum(case when col#=605 then 1 else 0 end) as 605,
sum(case when col#=608 then 1 else 0 end) as 608,
sum(case when col#=612 then 1 else 0 end) as 612,
sum(case when col#=600 then 1 else 0 end) as 600
from <tableName> group by partNumber;
```

Comment: I tried implementing this no luck as of yet, I'm using a AS-400 with Showcase query it has its limitations.